# CTE Producing Unexpected Result

Tags: sql-server

I'm wanting a percentage of each person's sales of Grand Total. I'm expecting 4 Records per SalesPersonID, one for each year.  I'm getting 16 records per SalesPersonID.  The Grand Total results are showing four different amounts for each year.  When I run the query alone it get's the correct result.

```
WITH gt as (
  Select sum(subtotal + taxamt) as YearlyGrandTotal
    , YEAR(OrderDate) as gtYear
  From AdventureWorks2017.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  group by YEAR(OrderDate)
),
it as (
  Select SalesPersonID, sum(subtotal + taxamt) as IndividualSales 
    , year(OrderDate) as SalesYear
  From AdventureWorks2017.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
  where SalesPersonID is not null
  Group by SalesPersonID, year(OrderDate)
)
Select SalesPersonID,SalesYear, IndividualSales,YearlyGrandTotal
  , 100*(IndividualSales/YearlyGrandTotal) as PercentageTotalRevenue
From gt,it
Group by SalesYear,SalesPersonID,IndividualSales,YearlyGrandTotal
order by SalesPersonID;
```

Comment: You're cross joining `gt` and `it` (using outdated syntax to boot). Presumably you want to join on year?

Comment: `From gt, it` will execute "cross joining" which produce 4 rows of data in `gt` and 4 rows in `it` into 16 rows - exactly what you are getting right now.

Comment: Joining fixed it.  Thanks, But what would be the updated syntax for this?